# group by and select row with the max date, and select all columns

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have the following data in a sheet.

| event_id | event_type | event_name | date_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | critical_event | Event A | 2021/12/16 |
| 456 | critical_event | Event B | 2021/12/25 |
| 999 | medium_event | Event C | 2021/12/13 |
| 888 | medium_event | Event D | 2021/12/16 |

I'm using the following query in another tab which would give me the latest event for each event_type (by using max(date_col)).

```
=QUERY(data!A:C, "select B, max(D) group by B")
```

However the query only returns the data for 2 columns.

| event_type | max date_col |
| --- | --- |
| critical_event | 2021/12/25 |
| medium_event | 2021/12/16 |

while what I want is to include the event_id and event_name columns as well. (Selecting that row which has the max date) Like below:

| event_id | event_type | event_name | max date_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | critical_event | Event B | 2021/12/25 |
| 888 | medium_event | Event D | 2021/12/16 |

If I select the event_id column in the query, the query breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to not break query you would need to use:

```
=QUERY(data!A:C, "select A,B,max(C) group by A,B")
```

but try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A1:C, 3, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to group by multiple columns. Is there anyway I could get the other columns' values of that row which has the max date value?

Comment: @Imran did you try 2nd formula?

Comment: 2nd formula works! I think that, accordingly to what OP posted originally the range set was data!A1:C, but it should be `data!A2:D` . Could you try @Imran?

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I was understanding how the sortn and sort formula works.It's working. Thank you guys.
Also, how fast is it going to be if we have like thousands of rows?

Comment: @Imran sorting operations are ono of fastest one so even with 10K rows it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query.
All the required columns will be displayed.

**=QUERY(data!A:C, "select **A,** B, max(C) group by A,B")**

Comment: Thanks, but can this be done without grouping by multiple columns? Not necessarily using queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return the rows where `date_col` has the max value, use:

```
={A1:C1;FILTER(A2:C5,C2:C5=MAX(C2:C5))}
```

[image]